# Create new Nx Mono-repo for existing Angular 14 and Vue3(Vite) apps

Tags: angular, vue.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

Is it possible to create a new Nx mono-repo for two existing Apps, one in Angular 14 and the other in Vue3 using Vite?

Another bonus would be to have an Asp.Net application also in the same mono-repo.

From what I have seen and attempted; it was hard enough to migrate an existing Angular app to Nx; and this would be also due to the complexity of the existing App.

Also I have noticed that Vue3 and Nx are still not completely integrated - as in not production ready.

Any sample projects/apps that do this would great as my searchs have not landed any.

Comment: What if instead of migrating, you create the a new Nx repo and combine both first well. Then you gradually migrate the code into the different apps?

Comment: Yeah, I'd do that, but I am still to verify that Nx mono repo for Vue and Angular is a viable (production ready) setup

Comment: Oh okay, I understand, well attempt and verify yourself, then tell us. Thank you!